# Set focus to last button clicked in Gridview after Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, focus, itemtemplate

I have a button in my gridview 
the grid can sometimes have many rows

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DDT">
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Button ID="DdtUnit" runat="server" Text=" -1 "  
                    CommandName="DdtUnit" 
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CaseID")+ ";" + Eval("CaseworkerID")+ ";" + Eval("EventDate")+ ";" + Eval("EventID")+ ";" + ("-1")+";"+((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>'/>
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

The command arguments get passed to a stored procedure, then i have a `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);`

I want to then return to the same place on the page just getting to same row would do
but even better would be to have the focus on the same button that was just clicked.

I have tried setting `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack ="true"` in the page directive but that didnt work with IE (im only interested in IE at this point)

so i tried passing `((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex` to a session variable 
an then doing

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack == false)
            {
                BindGridVeiw_Timeevents(MainCaseRef);
                Timeevents.Rows[MySession.Current.gridFocusIndex].Focus();
            }


        }
```

But im getting Nowhere, What am I missing?

EDIT:

```
 protected void Timeevents_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
}
```

i think im getting somewhere!   at least i dont need this anymore on the end of my command arg

> +";"+((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex

now i just need to get the actual button (i didnt mention earlier theres more than 1 button on each row)

Comment: i think im passing the wrong thing and i shouldnt be be passing the row index as a command argument because I get the row index from the onRowcommand event handler .... i think ?? .... if i need to store something as a session variable it should be the GridviewRow as as object..??  and the button itself....  maybe!

Comment: what exactly do you want from your command argument? do you just need the rowindex out of it?

Comment: I dont think i need to put the row index into the command argument do I?  i think what i need to do is use the onRowcommand event handler to define the row and the column(button) where the event came from and hold the gridviewRow as a session variable so i can set it to have the focus after the response.redirect,  the command arguments just need to have the parameteres for the StordProc